# Syntax error, insert "ClassBody" to complete ClassDeclaration

Tags: java

```
package numberquebymethod;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoOfDigit 
{
    public  int digit(int num)
    {
        int count=0;
        class InnerDig
        {
            while(num!=0)
            {
                count++;
                num=num/10;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        int num=sc.nextInt();
        NoOfDigit ndg=new NoOfDigit();
        System.out.println(ndg.digit(num));
    }
}

//Getting error in line:Class InnerDig
```

Comment: what is this `class InnerDig` ?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Actually we can, that is what we call [*local class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html). Syntaxtical problem here is that `while` loop is placed directly inside that local class, instead of wrapping it in its method/constructor/initialization block. Or we can just remove that `class InnerDig` since it is never *used*.

Comment: @Pshemo huh, TIL. I never saw that.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. There are 2 problems with that code snippet.

1. You can not write a control statement(if, switch, for, while, do-while, etc) outside a method or an initializer block. So, the while loop inside the class body `InnerDig` is not valid.
2. Even if you put the loop inside a method inside the inner class, it still would not compile as inside local inner class, a variable(`count` in this scenario) from the container method (`digit`) can only be accessed if it is final or effectively final.